# pip: how to install a git pull request

Tags: python, pip

I want to install a git pull request with pip for testing in my local virtualenv. I want to install it directly from github, without creating a local git repository.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can add the exact commit to the URL by appending the hash:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/other-repository/project.git@remote_branch_name
```

example:

```
pip install --user git+https://github.com/d1b/pip.git@fix_pip_build_directory
```

Or to a single commit. But this does not get updated, if the pull request (remote branch) gets updated:

```
pip install --user git+https://github.com/d1b/pip.git@d89b5803db2b520e754b9b26b771d22121738637
```

Answer (score 64):

A neat feature that github gives you is that it preemptively merges pull requests and makes them available as a hidden ref you can fetch specially. This is great if you're building a CI system to test pull requests.

Up until recently, pip didn't support specifying these hidden refs, but in the last month, support has [landed](https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/737dfbfc71490b41ab92c6d49b0c303c0e197f46) in pip (confirmed working in 10.0.1) for this.

The following command will install the merged version of pull request 123 for `user/repo`:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/user/repo.git@refs/pull/123/merge
```

Additionally, to install the unmerged version of pull request 123 (without messing with the github API to track down the original branch!):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/user/repo.git@refs/pull/123/head
```

Comment: Does pipenv share this functionality?


 EDIT: works, requires providing #egg=<package_name> option at the end

Comment: yep - this is also what you need to do in order to put this in a requirements.txt file for pip install -r

Comment: is "refs" literally the word "refs" here?

Comment: Yes, it is. refs is short for references, but you only type “refs”.