# How to install pull request using pip?

Tags: python, git, github, pip, pull-request

Can't figure out how to install this pull request:

```
https://github.com/shamanu4/dal_admin_filters/pull/23
```

I tried to find last commit:

```
https://github.com/shamanu4/dal_admin_filters/pull/23/commits/43f33db7c57058613a5410776575ce5f0f78357b
```

and run:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/shamanu4/dal_admin_filters/pull/23/commits/43f33db7c57058613a5410776575ce5f0f78357b
```

but it returns:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/shamanu4/dal_admin_filters/pull/23/commits/43f33db7c57058613a5410776575ce5f0f78357b
  Cloning https://github.com/shamanu4/dal_admin_filters/pull/23/commits/43f33db7c57058613a5410776575ce5f0f78357b to /tmp/pip-req-build-3uyhi6ui
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/shamanu4/dal_admin_filters/pull/23/commits/43f33db7c57058613a5410776575ce5f0f78357b/' not found
Command "git clone -q https://github.com/shamanu4/dal_admin_filters/pull/23/commits/43f33db7c57058613a5410776575ce5f0f78357b /tmp/pip-req-build-3uyhi6ui" failed with error code 128 in None
```

How to make it work? There is a fix I need on my `Django` project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use pip to install a package from a private github repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830856/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-to-install-a-package-from-a-private-github-repository)

Comment: @Torxed This is not a dup as the answer doesn't provide an URL to pull request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip: how to install a git pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561618/pip-how-to-install-a-git-pull-request)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+pull+request

Comment: I solved this by installing pip install git+https://github.com/belonesox/dal_admin_filters which is his fork which have all fixes I need.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with
`pip install git+https://github.com/shamanu4/dal_admin_filters.git@refs/pull/23/head`

or more generally, `pip install git+https://github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO>@refs/pull/<PR>/head`

Answer (score 0):

The commit is not pushed into master.

```
➜  dal_admin_filters git:(master) git checkout 43f33db7c57058613a5410776575ce5f0f78357b
fatal: reference is not a tree: 43f33db7c57058613a5410776575ce5f0f78357b
➜  dal_admin_filters git:(master)
```

You should follow the steps described [here](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/).

Else, you can simply edit the files locally I think. [There aren't much changes](https://github.com/shamanu4/dal_admin_filters/pull/23/files)

Else, you can create your own git repo, clone that repo and include the changes from the `__init__.py`. However, in that case you can't track changes committed to the repo.

Comment: The thing is that I want it to be in requirements.txt so it can be automatically installed so I would not prefer editing files locally.