# Cannot install geograpy python package in Ubuntu 16.04.5

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, nltk

I tried following command

```
pip3 install geograpy
```

A warning came

```
WARNING! You are attempting to install newspaper's python2 repository on python3. PLEASE RUN `$ pip3 install newspaper3k` for python3 or `$ pip install newspaper` for python2

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ulhaaak8/newspaper/
```

After I tried

```
pip3 install newspaper3k
```

It successfully installed

after i tried previous command again. but the same error came again.

Comment: https://github.com/ushahidi/geograpy/issues/27

Comment: It didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

geograpy's `setup.py` [declares `newspaper` as a dependency](https://github.com/ushahidi/geograpy/blob/6d99e787a9767bdc67fd6bf6face8df7bf3b95e9/setup.py#L23). This is a bug in `setup.py`; for Python 3 the dependency must be `newspaper3k`. Perhaps there are other problems with Python 3.

[There is a pull request](https://github.com/ushahidi/geograpy/pull/24) that fixes installation with Python 3.

Comment: I couldn't find the setup.py file in  venv/lib/site-packages/geograpy. Where can I find that file?

Comment: `site-packages/` contains only [importable package](https://github.com/ushahidi/geograpy/tree/6d99e787a9767bdc67fd6bf6face8df7bf3b95e9/geograpy) but not development files of which `setup.py` is just one. Clone the directory, apply the pull request and run `pip install .`. Or [install directlry from the pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50095199/7976758).

Answer (score 0):

I changed the default python version(2.7) to 3.6 in my Ubuntu system. After that the problem solved. Go to this
[link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu)