# How to state in requirements.txt a direct github not merged Pull request

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, github, requirements.txt

*My English is bad.*

I'm going to state some Python 3 library in `requirements.txt`, but there is a bug in original version of code. In **Pull requests** one user commited the new version with bug fix that **wasn't merged** by Author if it affects something.

The link looks like this: https://github.com/ramusus/kinopoiskpy/pull/47/commits/4c888bf4f6b330b115d11fac3e0b8bb177b597bb

**How should i write to requirements.txt so that it installs without any problem?**

I tried that: `-e git+git://github.com/ramusus/kinopoiskpy.git@4c888bf4f6b330b115d11fac3e0b8bb177b597bb#egg=kinopoiskpy`.

But there was an `ERROR: "git checkout -q 4c888bf4f6b330b115d11fac3e0b8bb177b597bb" failed with error code 128`

Comment: probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/9617336/3521116

Comment: @warl0ck Not related at all.

Comment: @warl0ck Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+%5Bpip%5D+pull+request

Comment: See [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50095199/7976758) about preemptively merged pull requests and their hidden refs.

Comment: @phd I've tried it. In my local venv repo it worked, although there was a "WARNING: Did not find branch or tag '...' ". But when i try to deploy it on Heroku, it showed me the same error but didn't work. I don't even know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your `requirements.txt` put the URL:

```
git+https://github.com/ramusus/kinopoiskpy@refs/pull/47/merge#egg=kinopoiskpy
```