# Heroku deploy fails to find dependency given as GitHub pull request URL in requirements.txt

Tags: python, github, heroku, requirements.txt

There is an answer to my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958482/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-not-merged-pull-request/55959742#55959742) that I tried to do.

I created **virtual-env local repository**, where I installed `requirements.txt` with: `git+https://github.com/ramusus/kinopoiskpy@refs/pull/47/merge#egg=kinopoiskpy`.

[image: Screenshot_1]

It was installed successfully, although there was `WARNING: Did not find branch or tag`.

And then I tried to push `requirements.txt` **to my Heroku server** and re-deploy.

[image: Screenshot_2]

And I don't even know what's the problem. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Please don't shorten relevant words just to save a fraction of a second. `req.txt` ≠ `requirements.txt`, and this makes your question confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried pointing to the source repository for the merge request as mentioned in the [question marked as a possible duplicate of your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561618/pip-how-to-install-a-git-pull-request)?

```
git+https://github.com/AlexanderNiMo/kinopoiskpy@4c888bf4f6b330b115d11fac3e0b8bb177b597bb
```

Comment: I just now realized that I could link it with user who pulled it. Thanks