# pipenv install a commit branch not working

Tags: git, pip, pipenv

I'm trying to install the package with this branch
https://github.com/arneb/django-messages/pull/149/commits/669decb149508e86fb43edef5274e9284dca66e7
via the code

```
winpty docker-compose exec web pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/arneb/django-messages.git@669decb149508e86fb43edef5274e9284dca66e7#egg=django-messages
```

I'm getting the error that 669decb149508e86fb43edef5274e9284dca66e7 is not a tree. I thought this is a commit reference? Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+pull+request

Comment: Esp. see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50095199/7976758: `pipenv install git+https://github.com/user/repo.git@refs/pull/123/merge` or `pipenv install git+https://github.com/user/repo.git@refs/pull/123/head`

Comment: In your case it should be `pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/arneb/django-messages.git@refs/pull/149/merge#egg=django-messages`

Comment: If you want to install an exact commit I think you cannot pull the commit from an umerged PR — you should install it from the fork: `pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/bgunebakan/django-messages.git@669decb149508e86fb43edef5274e9284dca66e7#egg=django-messages`

Comment: looks like I need a crash course in Git, I think the biggest issue here is that the commit is not merged. So the error - reference is not a tree, makes sense. Thank you so much. @phd

Comment: Now in my settings for my project, I used the reference name django_messages. Getting a new error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_messages'

Comment: "*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_messages'*" The most often cause for the problem is: you've installed the module using `pip` (or `pipenv`) running under one Python and now is trying to import the module in a different Python.

Comment: The installed app is inside my Pipfile and Pipfile.lock. So installation went through. They're all installed via docker so the Python version is locked...

Comment: Ok this is fixed now, I had to remove the editable:True in the pipfile. Thank you for your help I really appreciate it. Will delete this one soon due to it being a duplicate.