# import the forked-cloned version of a python module

Tags: pip

This might be a dumb question but I forked the Keras repo, cloned it, created a new branch, performed some modifications and created a PR.

Now I would like to use this module with my modifications.

To do that I would like to install it in a virtualenv. From what I have read there are two ways: one is to install it from the Pull Request link, the other from the local folder.

In the latter case I tried the command described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15031843/1714692):

```
pip3 install keras --no-index --find-links file:///home/my_usr/keras/
```

but I got the error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement keras (from versions: none)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for keras

In the former case I tried the command shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50095199/1714692) by running:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/keras-team/keras.git@refs/pull/16830/head
```

but in this case I got the error:

> ERROR: git+https://github.com/keras-team/keras.git@refs/pull/16830/head does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

I did some steps forward following [this guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-keras-from-source-a-follow-along-guide-2bcc4cea3aec) (being sure that I am on my correct branch) and using the same folder structure of the post.

However, after the steps, when importing `imdb` I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File
> "/home/my_user/keras_installation/keras/keras/**init**.py", line 21,
> in 
> from keras import models   File "/home/my_user/keras_installation/keras/keras/models/**init**.py",
> line 18, in 
> from keras.engine.functional import Functional   File "/home/my_user/keras_installation/keras/keras/engine/functional.py",
> line 27, in 
> from keras.dtensor import layout_map as layout_map_lib   File "/home/my_user/keras_installation/keras/keras/dtensor/layout_map.py",
> line 27, in 
> from keras.engine import base_layer   File "/home/my_user/keras_installation/keras/keras/engine/base_layer.py",
> line 43, in 
> from keras.saving.saved_model import layer_serialization   File "/home/my_user/keras_installation/keras/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py",
> line 22, in 
> from keras.saving.saved_model import save_impl   File "/home/my_user/keras_installation/keras/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 34, in 
> from keras.saving.saved_model import load as keras_load   File "/home/my_user/keras_installation/keras/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py",
> line 29, in 
> from keras.protobuf import saved_metadata_pb2 ImportError: cannot import name 'saved_metadata_pb2' from 'keras.protobuf' (unknown
> location)

Comment: This has nothing to do with *Git*. It's just a question about "how do I make Python import module M from path P2 instead of path P1". (The general answer is "via PYTHONPATH or equivalent such as venv")

Comment: Ok, you are right. Nevertheless, the problem remains. I tried to clarify my question with some examples. I hope I have improved my question

Comment: I think it is improved, yes - we now know you're looking for something that will help with pip3 as well (so I added that tag).

Comment: @francescoboi Have you checked pip's own documentation instead of possibly outdated StackOverflow answers? https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/

Comment: Installing from git: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/ -- Installing from local directory: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/local-project-installs/

Comment: Did you try navigating to your keras directory and running `pip3 install .`?

Comment: Also, you should never call `pip3` or `pip` or any `pipX.Y` script. Instead always use the `-m` form, something like `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install ...`, see: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: I found this resource: https://towardsdatascience.com/building-keras-from-source-a-follow-along-guide-2bcc4cea3aec. You cannot directly pip3 install but have to build first. However, after the build I cannot find the keras_pkg folder.