# How to install an umerged pull request with pip?

Tags: python, deap

I've tried the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561618/pip-how-to-install-a-git-pull-request) but can't get them working.

`pip install deap` installs the python2 version of deap on my RPi4b for some reason, even with python3.10 installed, as evident by some syntax errors.

I see that there is a [pull request](https://github.com/DEAP/deap/pull/591/files) that has the 2 to 3 conversions done in the files already. How can I pip install that pull request?

I've tried cloning deap and running `python3 setup.py install`, but it doesn't install the to appropriate `site-packages` folder for any script to see it installed. Any ideas?

Comment: I'll scrap my answer because a solution in your linked thread should work. `pip install "git+https://github.com/DEAP/deap@refs/pull/591/head"` should work for you (if it doesn't you probably need to quote the install URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pull request is created from a git branch, so you can install the specific branch by:

```bash
pip install -e git://github.com/{ reponame path }.git@{ tag or branch name }#egg={ desired egg name }
```

in your case:

```bash
pip install -e git://github.com/hidmic/deap.git@py3#egg=deap
```

Comment: why `-e`? what's the point of the editable install?

Comment: In fact there is no difference in this case, but usually we install a specific branch to test something, for that I added the -e. He can remove it, and replace the `git` protocol which is not supported in the regular mode by `git+http` (`pip install git+http://github.com/hidmic/deap.git@py3#egg=deap`)

Comment: This worked. Thanks! `pip install git+http://github.com/hidmic/deap.git@py3#egg=deap`